# How can sort an array without using sort() function in php?

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to sort an array without using sort() function of php. I have tried so far and also google but unable to find result.

### What I Need exactly

```
$arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);
```

I want to sort this array in ascending. i can do it using sort() function but I want to do without using sort() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Implementing QuickSort in PHP](http://pageconfig.com/post/implementing-quicksort-in-php)

or

[Quicksort recursive.php](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Quicksort_recursive.php)

```
function quicksort( $array ) {
    if( count( $array ) < 2 ) {
        return $array;
    }
    $left = $right = array( );
    reset( $array );
    $pivot_key  = key( $array );
    $pivot  = array_shift( $array );
    foreach( $array as $k => $v ) {
        if( $v < $pivot )
            $left[$k] = $v;
        else
            $right[$k] = $v;
    }
    return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivot_key => $pivot), quicksort($right));
}
```

**Usage :**

```
$arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);

$arr = quicksort($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: its working , there is nothing to wrong result is 

`Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 10 [2] => 50 [3] => 80 [4] => 90 [5] => 100 )`

Comment: I added usage please look

Comment: Why did you use `reset`, `array_shift` and `array_merge` in the function? Since OP requirements is not to use any PHP built in function.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for this:

```
<?php
$arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);

for($a = 0; $a < count($arr); $a++) {
    for($b = 0; $b < count($arr)-1; $b ++){
        if($arr[$b] > $arr[$b+1]) {
            $temp = $arr[$b+1];
            $arr[$b+1]=$arr[$b];
            $arr[$b]=$temp;
        }       
    }
}

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$srtArray=array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);
 for ($i=0; $i<count($srtArray); $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<count($srtArray); $j++) {
      // Compare two elements of array
      if ($srtArray[$j] > $srtArray[$i]){
        $tmp = $srtArray[$i];
        $srtArray[$i] = $srtArray[$j];
        $srtArray[$j] = $tmp;
      }
    }
 }
//Print an array after sorting
 for($i=0;$i<count($srtArray);$i++){
   echo $srtArray[$i]."<br>\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **QuickSort** because is practically the fastest way to sort an array of data. PHP's array sorting function `sort()` uses QuickSort. QuickSort is O(n log n).

```
<?php

$arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);

function quicksort( $array ) {
    if( count( $array ) < 2 ) {
        return $array;
    }
    $left = $right = array( );
    reset( $array );
    $pivot_key  = key( $array );
    $pivot  = array_shift( $array );
    foreach( $array as $k => $v ) {
        if( $v < $pivot )
            $left[$k] = $v;
        else
            $right[$k] = $v;
    }
    return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivot_key => $pivot), quicksort($right));
}

$array  = quicksort( $arr );

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 80
    [4] => 90
    [5] => 100
)
```

But if you can't use any built in function you can use this implementation of **BubbleSort**:

```
$arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);

 function bubbleSort ($items) {
     $size = count($items);
     for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
          for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
               if ($items[$j+1] < $items[$j]) {
                   arraySwap($items, $j, $j+1);
               }
          }
     }
     return $items;
 }
 function arraySwap (&$arr, $index1, $index2) {
     list($arr[$index1], $arr[$index2]) = array($arr[$index2], $arr[$index1]);
 }

$array  = bubbleSort( $arr );

print_r($array);
```

Reference:

> http://pageconfig.com/post/implementing-quicksort-in-php
>
> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#PHP
>
> http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Bubble_sort#PHP

Comment: Adrian Why did you use reset, array_shift and array_merge in the function? Since OP requirements is not to use any PHP built in function.

Comment: @ayazkhane OP says "without using sort() function" where are you read "without any PHP built in function"?

Comment: @ayazkhane if you want you can use the BubbleSort, I edit my answer

Comment: Note that if you know the distribution of values but not their order you can sort in O(n) time. For example you know there are values 1 .. 1000 but just don't know what order they're in, you can sort very quickly (even if it needs to be in-place). Even if you know that the values are, say, normally distributed and you know the standard deviations, you can still get faster than O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be the more optimized. Try this:

```
$arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3);

$count  = count($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++ ) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $count; $j++ ) {
        if ($arr[$i] > $arr[$j]) {
            $temp  = $arr[$i];
            $arr[$i] = $arr[$j];
            $arr[$j] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $arr = array(80, 90, 100, 10, 50, 3,34,1,890);

     for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

       for($x = 0; $x < count($arr)-1; $x ++){

    if($arr[$x] > $arr[$x+1]) {

        $temp = $arr[$x+1];
        $arr[$x+1]=$arr[$x];
        $arr[$x]=$temp;
    }       
   }
 }

 print_r($arr);
```